# Add class to parent on hover child:before

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="link"><a>Link</a></div>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
.link a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.link a:before {
  content: "+";
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

I'd like to add a class to the parent container if I hover just on `a:before` with jquery. I tried the following code, but I can't understand why this is not working:

```
$('.link a:before').hover(function () {
    $(this).parent('.container').addClass("selected");
});
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's not working because pseudoelements can't be accessed by javascript because they don't really exists in the DOM

Comment: Try with this: `$(element).before()`

Comment: @Jimmy Adaro thanks but that's not working unfortunately. Will need to set it up differently I guess